# Font Size Constraints in XCode6's Interface Builder With Custom Fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I'm using XCode6's Interface Builder with different size classes, and want to create a UILabel with a custom font that has a different font size constraint for different screen sizes. According to apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH12-SW1

you should be able to accomplish this by clicking the + icon next to the font field in the property inspector and choosing different font sizes for the different size classes.

This seems to work perfectly well for me when using system or other fonts that already come embedded in XCode, however, when I use a custom font that I've manually embedded in my project, it no longer respects the constraints and defaults back to the system font and the default font size.

Is this a bug with XCode, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you add your fonts to the plist file?

Comment: I can confirm this happens in Xcode 7 for fonts that are specified properly from the plist. If you don't change the size on a size class basis, the font works fine. If you do, the font size stops working. Looks like a bug, let's all radar it.